# Merge and update value from different sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, google-query-language

Good day! I need to merge and update values from status column of STAT sheet sent to status of DATA.

[image]

Comment: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"", 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({
 IF(STAT!A2:A="",,STAT!A2:A&"×"), STAT!C2:C&",", ROW(STAT!C2:C)&STAT!C2:C}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)), "×")), ",$", ), 2, 0)))
```

[image]